# How automatize date in menu section on Wix dashbord?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, wix

I just created a site on Wix and i would like to sell a dishes depending the day, the problem is, I must to put the dishes each time MANUALLY on the dashbord > menu > sections , I don't know use wix too much, I saw they have an API on here : https://dev.wix.com/api/iframe-sdk/sdk/wix.dashboard ...but i can't find this.

[image]

My question is: it possible to create a script on the dashboard to increment the date in advance ?
Where i can host the script?
Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

In `browser.get(url+val)` you are using `val`, which is defined in the previous for loop, in each iteration. You should change the second for loop in something like

```
for follower in followers:
        #Iterate into the list
        browser.get(follower)
```